# is there code example or api reference for “convergence”?

Tags: unity, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I cannot find any code example for writing apps for “convergence”.
Does anyone know it where I could find any? 
Or will anyone give some clue about how to write a convergence app for both phone and PC?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Head over to [developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com).

There you'll find how to install the Ubuntu SDK and some tutorials (like [this one](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/tutorial/building_your_first_qml_app/) for instance) that contain code examples.

Good luck!